# Converting only certain nodes in D3 Sankey chart from rectangle to circle

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I would like to reproduce the process from [D3 Sankey chart using circle node instead of rectangle node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208119/d3-sankey-chart-using-circle-node-instead-of-rectangle-node?lq=1), however, I would like to select only certain nodes to change from rectangles to circles.

For example, in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zf43j/) used in the example, how would you only select `Node 4` and `Node 7` to be converted to a circle?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zf43j/10/).

Basically you just need some way to select the nodes that you want to make different. I used unique classname so that you can style them with CSS as well. I didn't feel like writing the code to select just 4 and 7 (I'm lazy) so I just selected all of the even nodes instead.

```
// add in the nodes
var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function (d, i) { return i % 2 ? "node rect" : "node circle";
})
```

Then you can use that to select the nodes and add circles instead of rectangles.

```
svg.selectAll(".node.circle").append("circle")
    .attr("r", sankey.nodeWidth() / 2)
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.dy/2; })
    .attr("cx", sankey.nodeWidth() / 2)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also another similar approach, illustrated in the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2v0n4ydj/).

[image]

---

I started from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7RATu/) (from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208119/d3-sankey-chart-using-circle-node-instead-of-rectangle-node) that you merntioned)), where all nodes had already been converted to circles:

[image]

Then I modified existing and added some new code that involves filtering during creation of circles:

```
// add the circles for "node4" and "node7"
node
    .filter(function(d){ return (d.name == "node4") || (d.name == "node7"); })
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", sankey.nodeWidth()/2)
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return d.dy/2;
    })
    .attr("r", function (d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.dy);
    })
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, ""));
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", ".9")
    .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
    .style("stroke", function (d) {
        return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2);
    })
    .append("title")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value);
    });

// add the rectangles for the rest of the nodes
node
    .filter(function(d){ return !((d.name == "node4") || (d.name == "node7")); })
    .append("rect")
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return d.dy/2 - Math.sqrt(d.dy)/2;
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.dy);
    })
    .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, ""));
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", ".9")
    .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges")
    .style("stroke", function (d) {
        return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2);
    })
    .append("title")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value);
    });
```

Similar code had to be modified for accurate positioning text beside rectangles.

I believe the final result looks natural, even though it lost some of the qualities of the original Sankey (like wider connections).