# Where is d3.svg.diagonal()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I was trying to execute the code of collapsible-tree as mentioned [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083).  But it seems the diagonal method is not applicable in v4 (I may be wrong).

For:

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'diagonal' of undefined

What is the equivalent in v4?  Looking at d3.js API reference didn't give me any clue.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

D3 version 4.9.0 introduced [link shapes](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#links), which have the same functionality of the old `d3.svg.diagonal` in D3 v3.

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#links):

> The link shape generates a smooth cubic Bézier curve from a source point to a target point. The tangents of the curve at the start and end are either vertical, horizontal or radial.

There are three methods:

- [d3.linkHorizontal()](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#linkHorizontal)
- [d3.linkVertical()](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#linkVertical)
- [d3.linkRadial()](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#linkRadial)

So, for a collapsible tree like that one you linked, you define the path `d` attribute as:

```
.attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
    .x(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.x; }));
```

**Demo**:

Suppose you have an object with `source` and `target`, each one with `x` and `y` properties:

```
var data = {
  source: {
    x: 20,
    y: 10
  },
  target: {
    x: 280,
    y: 100
  }
};
```

First, you create the link generator:

```
var link = d3.linkHorizontal()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });
```

And then you can draw the path just by passing that data to the link generator:

```
.attr("d", link(data))
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = {
  source: {
    x: 20,
    y: 10
  },
  target: {
    x: 280,
    y: 100
  }
};

var link = d3.linkHorizontal()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });

svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", link(data))
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "darkslateblue")
  .style("stroke-width", "4px");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: How do you import (es6) the `d3.linkHorizontal()` part?

Comment: @erp import { linkHorizontal } from 'd3-shape'

Comment: Looks like someone mirrored your answer on their website here: https://www.tutorialguruji.com/javascript/where-is-d3-svg-diagonal/

Answer (score 23):

See GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/issues/27).

While the issue is still open, it doesn't seem that Mr. Bostock is in a rush to re-implement it in version 4.  Why?  Because it's trivial to implement yourself:

```
function link(d) {
  return "M" + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x
      + "C" + (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2 + "," + d.source.x
      + " " + (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2 + "," + d.target.x
      + " " + d.target.y + "," + d.target.x;
}
```

Comment: Like in your example above, I have seen many instances where 'y' is used for 'x' and vice versa.  What is the reason?

Comment: @MupparthyRavindranath, horizontol vs vertical drawing for tree layouts.  Vertical drawing reverses the x and ys like like [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ff91c1558bc570b08539547ccc90050b)

Answer (score 17):

I had a really hard time with this and then after a couple of hours, I realized how easy it really is (just like everyone else that mentions it).  Replace:

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
```

...with this:

```
var diagonal = function link(d) {
  return "M" + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x
      + "C" + (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2 + "," + d.source.x
      + " " + (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2 + "," + d.target.x
      + " " + d.target.y + "," + d.target.x;
};
```

That should be the only change.  Hope this helps anyone else.  This should work with a visualization like [Patrick Brockman's Collapsible/Searchable Tree](http://bl.ocks.org/PBrockmann/0f22818096428b12ea23).

Comment: How is this different from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40846487/4235784)?

Comment: Apologies.  I just want to add additional clarification.

Comment: I find this answer clearer because it mentions explicitly which part is to be replaced by which other part. That is exactly what one is looking for. In the other answers, it is not clarified what exactly is to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

For those with vertical trees, the function below will yield curved diagonals such as shown in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/anotherjavadude/2952964).

This function was modified from Mark's answer by (1) switching the x and y calls, and (2) changing the calculated coordinates in the two middle lines. Without the coordinate change, the curve is inverted such as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007877/how-to-use-the-d3-diagonal-function-to-draw-curved-lines).

```
var diagonal = function link(d) {
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y
      + "C" + d.source.x + "," + (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2
      + " " + d.target.x + "," + (d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2
      + " " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
};
```

As a side note, you can replace `"C"` with `" "` if you want boxy, instead of curved, edges.