# D3 collapsable tree path labels upside down

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using d3 to create collapsable tree. Pretty much following this [guide](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd).

I am trying to add labels to path.

Here is my code to add labels to path.

```
  var text = this.svg.append("text")
             .append("textPath")
             .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
             .attr("xlink:href", "#blahblah")
             .text((d)=> { return d.weight; });
```

The labels are rendered upside down the path. Not sure, what exactly is wrong. Any suggestions?

**Update**

Here is my path code

```
  let link = this.svg.selectAll('path.link')
  .data(links, function (d) {
    return d.id;
  });

// Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
let linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', 'g')
  .attr('class', 'link')
  .attr('id', (d) => {
    return d.id;
  })
.attr('d', (d) => {
  let o = { x: source.x0, y: source.y0 };
  return this.diagonal(o, o);
});

let linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

// Transition back to the parent element position
linkUpdate.transition()
  .duration(this.duration)
  .attr('d', (d) => {
    return this.diagonal(d, d.parent);
  });

// Remove any exiting links
let linkExit = link.exit().transition()
  .duration(this.duration)
  .attr('d', (d) => {
    let o = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
    return this.diagonal(o, o);
  })
  .remove();

 private diagonal = (s, d) => {
      let path = `M ${s.y},${s.x}
                  C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2},${s.x},
                  ${(s.y + d.y) / 2},${d.x},
                  ${d.y},${d.x}`;

      return path;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Your text path sources ("#blahblah") seem to have the paths the wrong way around (going right-to-left). Please show the code that constructs those paths.

Comment: @ccprog thank you. updated my question with path code.

Comment: what if you swap the `s` and `d` parameters of the `diagonal` function?

Comment: @rioV8 thank you. It worked.

Comment: Have a look at your `d` attributes of the `path` elements. They most likely contain a lot of white space because template strings are multiline

Comment: @Aj1 Since this is D3 v4/v5, why don't you use link shapes? Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44760465/5768908

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link is drawn by this function:

```
private diagonal = (s, d) => {
    let path = `M ${s.y},${s.x}
                C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2},${s.x},
                ${(s.y + d.y) / 2},${d.x},
                ${d.y},${d.x}`;

    return path;
}
```

So, it goes from the point in the first argument to the second. Accordingly, your update function should swap the arguments:

```
linkUpdate.transition()
  .duration(this.duration)
  .attr('d', (d) => {
    return this.diagonal(d.parent, d);
  });
```